# Looping through an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, casting

In my Tic Tac Toe game I have an array declared as follows:

```
static char[] boardArray = new char[9]{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'};
```

And I have a

```
private static void resetBoard(ref char[] arr)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char)i;
    }
}
```

However when I call this method:

```
resetBoard(ref boardArray);
```

It sets all array values to an empty char.
Why is that happening?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `new char[9]{...}`?

Comment: it's strange, that your boardArray is a length of 5, while you try to put inside 9 elements

Comment: @Mysterion: I'm guessing the OP typed this in instead of copying. That might also explain the mysterious `b` after the array declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I does not set them to empty but to the ASCII values 0 - 9, which is very different from the characters '0' - '9'.

What you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) 
{
   arr[i] = (char)(i + '0');
}
```

And by the way,

- you don't need `ref` here, arrays are reference types.
- using `arr.Length` is more legible and probably faster

Comment: That are identical to ASCII. Let's not confuse things.

Comment: and using `arr.Length` assures you don't go out of bounds of the arra

Answer (score 1):

A few things are going on here.

(1) You don't need to use `ref`. Arrays are passed effectively by reference anyway. What that means is that any changes you make in a function that takes an array will be apparent to the caller of the function. A copy is not made.

(2) You are assigning ASCII (actually, Unicode, but it's irrelevant here) codes 0 through 8 to your array. I assume you want the actual digits, which would be something else. In that case, use this code instead, which converts the integer `i` to a string and gets the first character of that string (there will only be one character anyway):

```
arr[i] = i.ToString()[0];
```

(3) Make sure to use `arr.Length` in your `for` loop, as it allows you to change the size of your array without having to also update the code in your `for` loop. In general, avoid constants other than `0` and `1` in your code (as with all rules, there are plenty of exceptions).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, use `arr[i] = char.Parse(i.ToString());` rather than `arr[i] = (char)i;`.